# не (было) отмечено

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

> В исследованиях на мышах при введении натализумаба **не отмечено** ускорения деления клеток меланомы и лимфобластного лейкоза.
>
> В исследовании на морских свинках с применением доз, превышающих рекомендованные для человека, **не было выявлено** влияния натализумаба на репродуктивную способность самцов.

Источник один и тот же. Какая разница между "не отмечено/выявлено" и "не было отмечено/выявлено"? Могут ли эти конструкции быть синонимичными?

Из Национального корпуса русского языка (разные источники):

> У людей, получавших препарат, **не отмечено** нежелательных последствий, а результаты проб оказались положительными ― их иммунная система «помнит» введенную вакцину.
>
> При применении препарата с лечебной целью существенного подавления репродукции вируса **не было отмечено**.

Answer (score 2):

```
      Какая разница между "не отмечено/выявлено" и "не было отмечено/выявлено"?
       Могут ли эти конструкции быть синонимичными?
```

Да, это синонимичные конструкции.

Было - связочный глагол.

Связки служат для выражения грамматического значения полнозначных слов или для связи синтаксических элементов.

Основная функция связок сводится к выражению **предикативности** у сказуемых, **лексическое значение которых не содержит признаков времени и наклонения.** В результате синтаксического употребления связка используется в составных сказуемых (...стал работать, является студенткой..., ...быть учителем... и т.д.) и в безличном предложении (Было весело; Стало хмуро и пр.), где сказуемое выражено словом категории состояния.

У нас связка в форме прошедшего времени сочетается с кратким страдательным причастием, образованным от причастия прошедшего времени, по сути дублируя грамматическое значение времени: не отмечено = не было отмечено. Смысл один - кем-то когда-то не отмечено.
Вот если б причастие было настоящего времени, там связка играла бы важную роль в определении времени события по отношению к моменту речи: я любим, я был любим, я буду любим.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/GVOZDEV/s/stil608.htm

§ 404. 2) У сказуемых, выраженных кратким страдательным причастием прошедшего времени, в зависимости от употребления связки передается разное отношение к результату действия. Именно сказуемое, выраженное этим причастием без связки, имеет своеобразное значение, указывая не только на завершенность действия в прошлом, но и на сохранение результата этого действия в настоящем.

Так,

*Окно открыто* указывает на то, что окно открыли и что оно остается открытым;

*Материалы доставлены* указывает не только, что доставка была осуществлена, но и на то, что материалы имеются налицо.

При этом обычно более важным и представляется наличие материалов.

Фраза *Семафор открыт* указывает, что путь свободен и можно ехать. Такое значение времени, когда выражено завершение действия в прошлом и сохранение его результата в настоящем, носит название перфекта.

*Не отмечено ускорения деления клеток меланомы и лимфобластного лейкоза* - означает, что в прошлом не отмечалось ускорения и в настоящем времени не отмечается.

*Не было выявлено натализумаба на репродуктивную способность самцов* - означает, что не выявлялось в прошлом, но сейчас, может быть, выявили.

Розенталь:

Различие между сочетаниями

*книга издана*

и

*книга была издана*

заключается не в большей или меньшей отдаленности во времени (ср.: книга была издана в прошлом году – книга издана в XVII веке, где связка была отнюдь не вносит значения большей давности), а в том, что

1) при отсутствии связки имеется в виду наличие результата в настоящем,

2) при наличии связки – отнесение результата к прошлому; ср.:

«Мертвые души» написаны Гоголем. – Второй том «Мертвых душ» был написан Гоголем (но сожжен);

«Евгений Онегин» написан Пушкиным. – Десятая глава «Евгения Онегина» была написана Пушкиным (но не издана).

Comment: Находка из Розенталя полностью совпала с моим пониманием :)

Answer (score 2):

**Полные синонимы?**

**А так не бывает**, варианты всегда чем-то отличаются, и это общая закономерность языка. Другое дело, если не замечать этих различий.

Я уже не однажды слышу подобные вопросы, поэтому могу предположить следующее.

Вариант ***не отмечено*** сообщает нам о результатах завершенного действия на текущий момент **в общем плане**.

Вариант ***не было отмечено*** обычно связан  с какой-то **временной последовательностью предыдущих действий**, указанной в заданном предложении или в **контексте.** Иногда для этого употребляются **временные наречия.**

Таким образом, мы видим не просто результат действия, а результат, **отнесенный к определенному временному промежутку**. Это, в частности, видно из приведенных ниже примеров.

**Примечание.** Конечно, эти "правила" соблюдаются не строго, в некоторых случаях использование формы "не было" не кажется **обоснованным** чем-либо. Значение форм для пользователей **нивелируется, сглаживается**, и это свидетельствует о каких-то потерях языка, связанных с точностью изображения действительности.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса

**До сих пор не было отмечено** ни одной поломки, связанной с данным дефектом.

Но ведь то, что он делал, **никогда не было отмечено** нарочитой простотой, которая сродни упрощенству.

Препарат, **назначенный по предложенной схеме,** пациенты переносили хорошо. Токсических эффектов  не было отмечено.

Количество куколок **на 10-е сутки** достигло 60 %, но до конца эксперимента выхода имаго **не было отмечено**.

**На сегодняшний день** в мире можно выделить около четырех географических зон, где действие вируса почти **не было отмечено.**

Реакции на контрольное заражение **не было отмечено**, а величина ТМЛ **на 7-е сутки** находилась в пределах нормы.

Контролируемые исследования по оценке профилактической эффективности вакцины против гепатита А производства фирмы «Мерк, Шарп и Доум» ...показали, что среди вакцинированных **в течение 50132 дней** **не было отмечено** заболеваний гепатитом А.[ Сравнительное изучение реактогенности, безопасности и иммуногенности инактивированных вакцин против гепатита A // «Вопросы вирусологии», 2000.12.18

Comment: Не могу понять смысла последней цитаты. 50 тыс. дней тому С.П. Боткин только начал исследовать эту болезнь. А первые вакцины появились лет на 100 позже.

Comment: Вы меня заставили улыбнуться и вспомнить анекдот про Сталина с такой концовкой: "Я так и думал, что по первому предложению возражений не будет".  Да, с математикой здесь не всё гладко, но тогда с ответом в целом, как я полагаю, вы согласны? Спасибо.

Comment: Да, с ответом согласен.

Comment: Там сказано, что исследовали детей от 2 до 16 лет. 5132/365 = 14,06. Скорее всего, нолик лишний.

Comment: Да, забавно. Но вот, кроме вас, никто не заметил. Может быть, люди стали  менее внимательными и наблюдательными, много времени проводя в виртуальной реальности. Скоро будем различать только три цвета.

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ

Господи ты боже мой, опять этот **результат действия**!  Кажется, результат действия у нас обозначают прилагательные, здесь-то он откуда? А вот сейчас посмотрим…

**Проверим источники?**

1)  **§ 404 – это что такое?**  Гвоздев А.Н. Очерки по стилистике русского языка: учеб. пособие.  3-е изд. / Под ред. С. Г. Бархударова.– М.: Просвещение, **1965.**
Алекса́ндр Никола́евич Гво́здев (**1892—1959**) — советский лингвист, член-корреспондент АПН РСФСР.

Предисловие к изд.1965 года.

В декабре 1959 г. скончался известный советский языковед-русист, доктор филологических наук, профессор Александр Николаевич Гвоздев. Первую свою научную работу он опубликовал **в 1923 г**. И с тех пор в течение 36 лет он интенсивно и плодотворно занимался изучением русского языка.

Среди этих книг особое значение имеют **"Очерки по стилистике русского языка"** (первое издание вышло **в 1952 г**.). При почти **полном отсутствии глубокой разработки** проблем русской стилистики в лингвистической науке А. Н Гвоздеву удалось создать весьма полезное практическое руководство по стилистике русского языка. Автор прекрасно понимал трудности, стоящие перед ним. Он хорошо знал, что основные понятия, содержание и объем стилистики **еще четко не определены и не получили еще общепризнанного решения.**

Читатели должным образом оценили и полюбили этот труд А. Н. Гвоздева.. Правда, русская филологическая наука по семасиологии, по синонимике, по лексике и фразеологии, по грамматическому строю языка за последние годы добилась немалых успехов, в свете которых некоторые теоретические положения и наблюдения А. Н. Гвоздева кажутся теперь **устаревшими и спорными.**

Итак,  можно предположить, что далеко не всё, что написано в этих очерках, признавалось даже при жизни автора, а с развитием науки какие-то утверждения тем более становились **устаревшими.**

2) **Розенталь, источник не указан**.

А что там с примерами? **Примеры придуманные,  нет ничего хуже, чем изучать язык по таким примерам.** Если бы у Розенталя был Интернет и Нацкорпус, то разве он стал бы такими примерами пользоваться? Он взял бы их из живой речи, как это можем сделать мы.

Я не вижу в  современных текстах, приведенных в моем ответе, **ничего похожего на сохранившийся результат действия**.

Представьте себе, что вы экскурсовод. Вот перед вами старинный храм – явно сохранившийся  результат.  Как  сказать правильно:  *Храм построен (или был построен) в 19 веке архитектором Никитиным?*  Реально используются оба варианта, и с результатом действия это никак не связано.

Так что **перенесемся из 50-х годов** прошлого века в современный мир.  И вот она, наша жизнь, 2020 год: «***На сегодняшний день в мире можно выделить около четырех географических зон, где действие вируса  не было отмечено***».

Почему здесь «не было отмечено»? Обозначено время поступления данных (сегодняшний день), а сбор их происходил в течение определенного промежутка времени. Это и есть не общее обозначение завершенности действия, а отнесенность действия к течению времени. Не отмечено на сегодняшний день, а  в будущем возможны изменения.